# Sliding from current location upwards for jQuery effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a cart "jewel" (like those iOS app icon notifications) that slides up when a quantity of the cart is increased, and slides down when the quantity of the cart is decreased. This is the code:

JS:

```
$('#jewel').text('');
$.getJSON("{{ url('schedulizer/cart') }}", function(data) {

    if(data.quantity > 0) {
        $('#jewel')
                .show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 100)
                .text(data.quantity);
    } else {
        $('#jewel')
                .hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 100)
                .text(data.quantity);
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<button
    id="fixed-button"
    class="btn btn-fab btn-raised btn-material-yellow-600 mdi-action-list">
    <span id="jewel" class="jewel"></span>
</button>
```

The issue I am having is, the slide up effect isn't what I want. The icon in this case, slide from the TOP to the jewel location, instead of sliding from the jewel location to the top.

[image]

Comment: So did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are going for, or very similar.  They key is to animate it in one direction, then reposition it to come from the other side, then animate it again to the start

```js
cartItems=[];
$('.jewel').css('opacity','1');
$('#add').click(function(){
    cartItems.push('item');
    $('#fixed-button').children('.jewel').animate({
        marginTop:'-100px',
        opacity:0
    },200,function(){
        $('.jewel').html(cartItems.length);
        $('#fixed-button').children('.jewel').css('margin-top',100);
        $('.jewel').show();
    }).animate({
        marginTop:'20px',
        opacity:1
    },200);
});
$('#rem').click(function(){
    cartItems.pop();
    $('#fixed-button').children('.jewel').animate({
        marginTop:'100px',
        opacity:0
    },200,function(){
        $('.jewel').html($('.jewel').html()*1-1);
        $('#fixed-button').children('.jewel').css('margin-top',-100);
    }).animate({
        marginTop:'20px',
        opacity:cartItems.length?1:0
    },200);
});
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:sans-serif
}
#cart .btn{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FF0;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    box-shadow:4px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
.jewel{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:100%;
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#F00;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
    font-size:18px;
    display:none;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cart">
<div 
    id="fixed-button"
    class="btn btn-fab btn-raised btn-material-yellow-600 mdi-action-list">
    <span id="jewel" class="jewel">0</span>
</button>
</div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<button id="rem">Remove</button>
```

Comment: Hi there. Apologies. I have not tested your answer yet. I will get back to you, thank you.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage ok. but did you at least click "run code snippet" and see if it's basically does what you need?

Comment: Just tested this. It is exactly what I want. Thank you!! One minor thing. Could you hide the jewel (while also sliding down) when the count is 0?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage ok I updated it to not show when 0, and to show the number based off the length of a cartItems array